# Group dates by quarterly/Half yearly/weekly

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, group-by, strftime

I have a sql lite query that gets me the sum of amount daily/weekly/monthly/yearly basis.

But I want to be able to expand it so that I can custom group it i.e group by 3 months or half yearly etc.

Here is my query

```
SELECT sum(amt), strftime('%Y-%m',datetime(date_time)) as date
FROM sales
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date desc
```

The above code gets me the total amount for each month.

But how can I use the query to group by number of month like quaterly or half yearly?

Comment: If you want weekly then you will have to define more precisely what you mean by a week. There are lots of different definitions.

Comment: if it is an on the fly filtering and expanding (Drilldown) then I would sugest you that you get the data with minimum possable grouping (like the queery above) and then  format the data on the client side according to the needs

Comment: @Mark Byers to be more specific if i use format like %Y-%m i may get 2011-01,2011-02,2012-05 and so on. And i would want these dates to group by 3 months lets say month 01,02,03 in one group. Same goes with with week i get the week no when i use the format %Y-%m-%W so i may want to group it into 2 weeks etc.. i hope m clear

Comment: @Sarita: But the problem is that there is no universal definition for which week number each specific day has. In some systems January 10th might be in week 1, and other systems it might be week in 2 or maybe even 3. It depends on how you define weeks and how you count them. You need to be specific about which day is the first in the week and which week is the first in the year, and how to handle the special cases. Depending on your definition the SQLite '%W' may or may not meet your needs (but probably not).